# How to get notified when the recursive function with async fs.readdir completes execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I know when the recursive function with asynchronous fs.readdir has completed its execution?
Here complete execution means that all the files in the given directory are processed.

I've tried returning a promise and also used async/await for post-processing.

```
var func = (dirName) => {
    fs.readdir(dirName, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log('Total Size = ' + size);
            console.log('Size Processed = ' + fileSizeProcessed);
            console.log('Processing : ' + file);
            var currentDir = path.join(dirName, file).toString();
            if ((fs.statSync((currentDir)).isDirectory())) {
                func(currentDir);
            }
            else {
                //Process File
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the execution in a promise and then you can wait for the recursive call to be processed, stopping the execution in the context of the function if you use a for of. Finally, once all the files are processed, we resolve the final promise by notifying that everything is over.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const walk = dirName => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dirName, async (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      for (const file of files) {
        console.log(`Processing : ${file}`)
        const currentDir = path.join(dirName, file)
        if ((fs.statSync((currentDir)).isDirectory())) {
          await walk(currentDir)
        } else {
          console.log(`File ${file} processed`)
        }
      }
      resolve(`Folder ${dirName} processed, work finished`)
    })
  })
}

walk('./walk').then(response => console.log(response))
```

For example, in the following directory structure:

[image]

If you execute the above code, the output is as follows:

```
Processing : file1.txt
File file1.txt processed
Processing : file2.txt
File file2.txt processed
Processing : file3.txt
File file3.txt processed
Processing : walk-sub1
Processing : walk-sub1-1
Processing : walk-sub1-1-file1.txt
File walk-sub1-1-file1.txt processed
Processing : walk-sub1-file1.txt
File walk-sub1-file1.txt processed
Processing : walk-sub1-file2.txt
File walk-sub1-file2.txt processed
Processing : walk-sub2
Processing : walk-sub2-file1.txt
File walk-sub2-file1.txt processed
Folder ./walk processed, work finished
```

Remember to deal with errors in internal promises, I didn't do it to simplify the example

Comment: Thanks, this works. I actually did the exact same thing but with foreach loop. Any idea why did this happen?

Comment: Hi @SSG. When you use a forEach function, in each iteration you are creating a new context defined by the internal function of the forEach, so, the **await** instruction isn't in the external context (fs.readdir ), the execution doesn't stop and you are executing the internal recursive calls in parallel. You don't have the certainty that the global promise ends after the internal ones